# Custom error pages in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code somewhere in my controller:

```
raise PermissionDenied
```

When this is executed, I want to show a custom error page written in HAML, rather than the default `NameError` page.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rescue_from` method can be used for global exception handling.

Change the`app/controller/application_controller.rb` file to add the exception handler.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ::PermissionDenied, :with => :render_permission_denied

  def render_permission_denied(e)
    @error = e   # Optional, accessible in the error template
    log_error(e) # Optional 
    render :template => 'error_pages/permission_denied', :status => :forbidden
  end
end
```

Now add a haml file called `permission_denied.html.haml` in `app/views/error_pages` directory.

```
%h1 Permission Denied!
  %p #{@error.message}
```

Refer to the rails [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#M000554) for more details.

Comment: I get this erreur: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::PermissionDenied. Do you know what I can do?

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Did you add the change I suggested? Where have you declared the `PermissionDenied` class?

Comment: Oh I am so dumb xD. I hadn't declared it. Now I declared `class PermissionDenied < Exception` in `/lib/permission_denied.rb` and it works great now. Thanks +D